# When I assign value to the last column of the array, the first element on the next row updates too

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, malloc

```
typedef struct _PQ {
    short cost;
} PQ;
```

```
void Dijkstra(short** arr, short row, short col) {
    //initialize DIST

    PQ **table;
    table = malloc(sizeof(*table) * (row));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(table) * col);
    }


    // 1. graph
    for (short i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (short j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            table[i][j].cost = arr[i][j];
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("First run: %hd %hd\n", arr[0][4], table[0][4].cost);
            printf("%hd ", table[1][0].cost);
        }
    }
}
```

row is 5 and column is 4.
I'm currently inserting 5 (arr[0][4])  at table[0][4].cost
However, as soon as I insert the value to table[0][4].cost, table[1][0].cost updates with the same value.

Also after finish inserting the second row, my first row value changes.

After inserting the first row

> 4 2 1 0 5
>
> 5

After inserting the second row

> 4 2 1 0 2
>
> 2 0 4 1 0

and this happens every row. Last element on the row and first element on the next row are same.
I'm really not sure why this happens.

Also, I checked if my arr[i][j] value, but the arr is correct.

after inserting the second row,

I should have

> 4 2 1 0 5
>
> 2 0 4 1 0

instead of

> 4 2 1 0 2
>
> 2 0 4 1 0

I feel like it's related to pointer, but I'm not sure what to do

Comment: `sizeof(table)` should be `sizeof(PQ)`

Comment: `dist[i]` should be `table[i]`

Comment: Thank you sizeof(PQ) solved the problem!